# Connect and create a local Oracle databse

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I am new to Oracle. I had created a local Oracle database but I needed to drop it, so I dropped it using below commands.

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL> shutdown immediate;
SQL> startup mount exclusive restrict
SQL> drop database;
```

Now I need to recreate local Oracle db so I tried below commands but I am getting errors now.

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL> shutdown abort
SQL> startup
```

Getting errors on above command execution:

[image]

Also tried creating tablespace but getting below error:

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: As you dropped the database, now you first have to create it. You'd use CREATE DATABASE (not "tablespace").

Comment: But last time when I created local instance I connect as sysdba and created tablespace and after that i restored backup taken from production db. Please share some link if I am missing any step(s).

Comment: I don't even know sys user password if its required.

Comment: I don't have any link (should search for it, but - you can do it yourself). Moreover, I'm not a DBA (yes, I did that job a loooong time ago, but I'd rather not suggest anything any more) so I'd say that you should follow official Oracle documentation. SYS password isn't required (as you already saw, SQLPLUS / AS SYSDBA let you "in" because you ran it as operating system user who "owns" Oracle software on your computer). Finally, this is Stack Overflow (for developers). You'd rather go to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle.